# what are the limiting factors affecting concurrency in an Azure App Service (ASP.NET WebApi)?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, webapi

- our app services a series of 7 API calls for a user to complete a registration flow (it takes about 4 secs to complete a flow as there are a couple of slow steps)

It is an ASP.NET WebApi Azure Web App in an S1 tier (non-Production slot)

Using JMeter I find that we hit our maximum throughput (as measured by completed registrations / sec) with about 20 concurrent users. That seems a bit low.

What is limited our performance here?

It doesn't seem to be CPU or RAM as Azure is reporting they're not stretched.

Any hints on things that might be tunable? I have read that increasing the Thread Pool threads may help for example.
Obviously we can scale up to better hardware.

thanks,
Tiger99.

Comment: Instrument your app, look at the metrics, find the bottleneck, update the code, repeat.

Comment: the question isn't really about my code. A web application ought to scale quite well in terms of concurrency because each request can be handled in parallel - but I am seeing that even with a low number of concurrent users the performance has leveled off.. I am not sure what factors could be limiting it other than cpu/mem/disk performance.

Comment: do you have any database dependency or external API dependency and if yes, do you have some metrics on them? maybe they are slowing your api down. Also I assume that you have enabled auto scaling but the load is not causing the auto scale.

Comment: Without seeing metrics about the app, it's pretty hard to say what is the bottleneck here.